# how to pass dynamic values in drawchart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
var dataAsArray = [
       ["Student", "# items sold", "$ earned"],
       ['Alice', 40, 40],
       ['Bob', 20, 20],
       ['Catherine', 10, 30],
       ['Danny', 5, 50],
       ['Eva', 20, 20],
       ['Felipe', 50, 25],
       ['Gwen', 7, 15],
       ['Henry', 25, 25]
    ];
```

I want to create rows and columns something like above for passing to the googles drawchart().
same thing i want dynamically

```
       ['Alice', 40, 40],
       ['Bob', 20, 20],
       ['Catherine', 10, 30],
       ['Danny', 5, 50],
       ['Eva', 20, 20],
       ['Felipe', 50, 25],
       ['Gwen', 7, 15],
       ['Henry', 25, 25]
```

I have also try the following code

```
for (var i = 0; i < usersTable.length; i++) {

    tdata.addRow([usersTable[i].name, parseInt(usersTable[i].rank), parseInt(usersTable[i].age) ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I used the following:

```
var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

Then initialise headers of your table:

```
tdata.addColumn('string', 'User');
tdata.addColumn('number', 'Rank');
tdata.addColumn('number', 'Age');
```

Then loop throught your dynamic data and do the following inside your loop:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < usersTable.length; i++) {

        tdata.addRow([usersTable[i].name, parseInt(usersTable[i].rank), parseInt(usersTable[i].age) ]);
    }
```

Then finally draw your Chart:

```
chart.draw(tdata, options);
```

Comment: Can you show your data structure? How are you getting the data?

Comment: this problem is solve by using push method of javascript. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by using push method

```
var dataset = [['month','purchase','sale']];
for(var i =0; i < datasetArray.length; i++){
    dataset.push([datasetArray.mnt, datasetArray.purchase, datasetArray.sale]);
}
```

thanks.